# Virtual Network card on a real Windows 7 OS

Tags: windows-7, ethernet

How can I add a virtual ethernet card to connect to a different network through my physical ethernet card?

I need something like Vmware network adapter...but on a REAL OS...not virtual one..

Please help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but I get the feeling you want to connect to two networks on two different subnets, that are on the same physical LAN?

To do this, you can assign multiple IP addresses to the one network card, quite easilly.

You need to have a Static IP address assigned, and then in your TCP/IP Properties, click Advanced, and under IP Addresses, click Add and then add the different subnets you desire.

Comment: oh yeah,that works!! But,if internet does not work through one gateway,would it automatically work through the alternative gateway?

Comment: Hi Josh, I honestly don't know. Only one way to find out - add an additional gateway and find out! I'm fairly sure it would work though.